# What's the name of the music track that plays at 14:08 in Episode 764 of One Piece?

Tags: one-piece, music

What's the name of the music track that plays at 14:08 in Episode 764 of One Piece?

Please help me!!:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaTnLP78vfk)

> "Nami's Message ~Luffy's Anger~", track #22 of the album "Strong World".

Truth be told, I wanted to know too, and I finally found it! It's a soundtrack from Strong World, Nami's Message (or something along the lines of that).